# Is Google Colab ( free version) disconnects after laptop goes to sleep mode?

Tags: runtime, google-colaboratory, disconnect, sleep-mode

If I put the laptop in sleep mode, will colab going to be disconnected?

Comment: I think you will get about 12 hours straight running. Let's say you have a loop that goes running for 12 hours, so even when your laptop is on sleep mode the code will still run. Otherwise, I will be disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

Mine stopped when my laptop fell asleep, i was running it in GPU mode.